# What's adding shape and jQuery attributes to my anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application that's been behaving differently on different machines running exactly the same version of IE. By inspecting the html I found the anchor tag has some attributes being added at render time.

The machines it works on renders it as:

```
<a id="loadDate" href="...">Go</a>
```

But machines it doesn't work on renders it as:

```
<a id="loadDate" href="..." shape="" jQuery11...24="6">Go</a>
```

On click, both run the handler but the offending version evaluates a Boolean expression incorrectly. It could be failing on something else (it uses `parseInt` against `$(...).val()` in the expression) but unfortunately I cannot change the code to debug further without deploying which I'd prefer be a last resort. I assume this is something well known but my Google-fu is returning a lot about jQuery attributes not a jQuery attribute which isn't helpful.

What's adding the shape and jQuery attributes to my anchor tag and can I control it programmatically or is this browser settings?

Comment: /shrug. try seeing what other scripts are on the page...

Comment: could there be spyware or a proxy on the one machine?

Comment: @DanielA.White, it's not just one machine, it's numerous random machines.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a DOM breakpoint?

Comment: It's expando. It basically deals with memory leaks. It's an internal jQuery thing. Sorry, no virus for you. :) I'll try to find a duplicate.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, hmm, I thought I just found this issue has to do with IE compatibility view settings.

Comment: The good news is you don't need to worry about it. It's part of jQuery's struggle to keep your page running on as many browser/device combos as possible. It's why you use jQuery in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the dup, it does appear to answer the question, but it's being solved by changing the compatibility view settings in IE. It's browser specific, it works on all machines in FF, Chrome, etc. Just not IE and only with those with CVS on the url.

Comment: If you want to wait for an answer on yours I can de-dupe it. I don't want to argue over if it's a dupe or not. Tbh, I didn't know I'd dupe it single-handedly (I didn't realize it had `html` tag) - just wanted to show a similar one. On tags without gold your vote gets recorded and if more people agree, it gets duped.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, no worries no arguments here :) I'll probably just opt to delete it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177594/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-chieftwopencils).